# I want to change my fire simulation's background from black to white

Tags: eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

Basically, I want to change the background color from black to white in my fire simulation. But when I change it from "World" settings the details are lost. I'm new at blender and I know I should change the background color on "composition" tab but I didn't make it. Can someone help?
[image: Black]

[image: White]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color to transparent and add a color using any image or video editing program.
Just tick the "transparent" option under Film under Render Properties, as seen in the image

[image]